# What is the difference between an ideal clock and a physical clock in relativity

Tags: general-relativity, time

A letter from Einstein's friend Besso mentioned what Einstein called his "original sin." Einstein's sin was that he defined a clock to be both a physical thing (an actual clock) and an ideal entity based upon the constant speed of light. He defined the relativistic clock both ideally and concretely.This Einstein acknowledged leads to an inconsistency.  He argued that if he hadn't done this he could not give his results a physical interpretation and physics would be reduced to geometry.

I have questions about Einstein's "sin."

1. What is the contradiction Einstein is referring to?
2. How does it affect the time variable in relativity? Which clock is used in the definition of the time variable? Is the time variable always defined by one of the two clocks.
3. How can relativity be logically coherent if this contradiction exists.
4. Why couldn't there be a physical interpretation of relativity if Einstein chose only one of the definitions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you read this article, the start  of it might address your first question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation

Comment: Countto10 suggestion was informative. Einstein defined synchronization as follows: a light signal is sent from clock 1 at t1 to clock 2 and immediately back to clock 1 by a mirror. It reaches clock 1 at t3. Clock 2 is synched with clock1 by setting it according to t3= 1/2(t1+t2).  Einstein assumed that this definition of synchronization was "free from contradictions."  This definition is useful only if the synchronization is stable, reflexive, symmetric and transitive. There are some physical conditions that must hold